# Oracle Sequential actions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table of data detail the action sequence of a row on a parent table where column ID is that foreign key. Column SEQ is the order in which those actions took place and ACTION is what took place.

```
ID          SEQ ACTION
12345.00    2   SUSPEND
12345.00    3   CLEAR
12345.00    4   SUSPEND
12345.00    6   CLEAR
12345.00    7   SUSPEND
12345.00    8   RESUME
12345.00    9   SUSPEND
12345.00    10  RESUME
12345.00    11  CLEAR
```

I am trying to present the data in such a way that I can identify SUSPEND and RESUME actions that were not cleared. In this scenario my result would look like this;

```
12345.00    7   SUSPEND    8    RESUME
12345.00    9   SUSPEND
```

This is the case because;

> SUSPEND action 2 was removed by CLEAR action 3.
>
> SUSPEND action 4 was removed by CLEAR action 6.
>
> RESUME action 8 was removed by CLEAR action 9.

The ACTION column can have other actions in the sequence so I have removed those for clarity.

An action is cleared if it will be succeeded by a CLEAR.

Sorry if this is confusing. I cannot change the schema!

I have tried to simplify the question;

```
ID          SEQ ACTION
12345.00    2   SUSPEND
12345.00    3   RESUME
12345.00    4   CLEAR
12345.00    5   RESUME
12345.00    6   SUSPEND
```

The result should look like this;

```
12345.00    2   SUSPEND   5 RESUME
12345.00    6   SUSPEND
```

I have tried a couple of approaches but I just cannot figure how to stop the RESUME at number 3 being included.

Comment: action 9 is suspend. I am a bit puzzled over this.

Comment: Action 10 "RESUME" was cleared so the SUSPEND action has not been terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Now I steal fiddle from [kordirko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/kordirko) and concept from [simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990451/simon) and cook it in my way.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
   "ID"       INT,
   "SEQ"      INT,
   "ACTION"   VARCHAR2 ( 7 )
);

INSERT ALL
INTO   TABLE1 ( "ID", "SEQ", "ACTION" )
VALUES ( 12345.00, 2, 'SUSPEND' )
INTO   TABLE1 ( "ID", "SEQ", "ACTION" )
VALUES ( 12345.00, 3, 'RESUME' )
INTO   TABLE1 ( "ID", "SEQ", "ACTION" )
VALUES ( 12345.00, 4, 'CLEAR' )
INTO   TABLE1 ( "ID", "SEQ", "ACTION" )
VALUES ( 12345.00, 5, 'RESUME' )
INTO   TABLE1 ( "ID", "SEQ", "ACTION" )
VALUES ( 12345.00, 6, 'SUSPEND' )
   SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

So what I understand from your problem is that its is not explained correctly initially. But the second expected result does the trick. (I might be still wrong)

```
WITH AFTER_CHECK
     AS (SELECT T.ID,
                T.SEQ,
                T.ACTION,
                CASE
                   WHEN ACTION = 'CLEAR'
                   THEN
                      1
                   WHEN LEAD ( ACTION ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SEQ) =
                           'CLEAR'
                   THEN
                      1
                   ELSE
                      0
                END
                   AS IGNORE_CURRENT
         FROM   TABLE1 T)
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT T.ID,
               T.SEQ,
               T.ACTION,
               LEAD ( SEQ ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SEQ) NEXT_SEQ,
               LEAD ( ACTION ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SEQ)
                  NEXT_ACTION
        FROM   AFTER_CHECK T
        WHERE  IGNORE_CURRENT = 0)
WHERE  ACTION = 'SUSPEND';
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
12345   2   SUSPEND 5   RESUME
12345   6   SUSPEND
```

What I did was assigning a flag to check consecutive actions set to be ignored if they have an ACTION called `CLEAR` or a NEXT ACTION called `CLEAR`. Then I used kordirko's snippet of `LEAD` function to do the job with a filter on needed ACTION.

**See the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/596b0/1/0)**

Comment: what happen if you have two `SUSPEND` actions in a row?

Comment: logically and practically not possible... But a data setup can be done and it is not handled. If OP can confirm this case, we can rework. Solution is purely based on what OP has requested for..

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT t.*,
          lead( SEQ ) over ( partition by id order by seq ) next_seq,
          lead( action ) over ( partition by id order by seq ) next_action
   FROM table1 T
)
WHERE action = 'SUSPEND'
  AND next_action <> 'CLEAR'
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ea45/8

Comment: Really close...but the last RESUME action has been cleared so we would not want to see it.

Comment: wouldn't this solution work if it was changed to: WHERE action in ('SUSPEND','RESUME') ?  Anyway, +1

Answer (score 3):

I tried from sqlfiddle of **kordirko**, to avoid building the same schema... Sorry for stealing.

See my attempt here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ea45/22

```
select *
from (select id,
             seq,
             min(case when action != 'SUSPEND' then seq end) over (partition by id order by seq rows between current row and unbounded following) nxt
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(action) over (partition by id order by seq) nxt
            from table1 t)
      where nxt != 'CLEAR'
        and action != 'CLEAR')
where (seq != nxt or nxt is null)
```

The idea is:

1. Take only the actions which are not cleared and not "clear" by themselves
2. Find out the next action which is "resume" by looking only into the future and getting minimum
3. Filter the result to exclude "current row"

The only thing left to do is to add names of actions which is quite simple, because every first action is "SUSPEND" and second, if it is not null, "RESUME". This I guess you can easily do by yourself as you wish :)

Answer (score 2):

This modified version of kordirkos solution should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT t.*,
          lead( SEQ ) over ( partition by id order by seq ) next_seq,
          lead( action ) over ( partition by id order by seq ) next_action
   FROM table1 T
)
WHERE action in ('SUSPEND', 'RESUME')
  AND (next_action <> 'CLEAR' or next_action is null)
```